# scala macro with fresh identifier

Tags: scala, macros, scala-quasiquotes

I have a macro which I want to use to log the time it takes to execute a block that might return something useful. So if I have something like
`val y = f(x)` I will change to `val y = Timed(f(x))` to get the time it took to execute the function in the log.

I almost have what I want, but when using fresh term names to avoid name collision, for example between t0 and t1, I'm getting an error:

```
Error:(22, 15) Can't unquote reflect.runtime.universe.TermName, consider providing an implicit instance of Liftable[reflect.runtime.universe.TermName]
         val $kk = System.nanoTime()
          ^
```

How to get those freshTermNames working with the quasiquotes?

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe ⇒ u }

object Timed {
  def apply[T](block: ⇒ T): T = macro Timed.apply_impl[T]

  def apply_impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(block: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[T] = {
    import c.universe._
    implicit val cc: c.type = c
    val kk = u.internal.reificationSupport.freshTermName("kk")
    val t0 = c.freshName("t0")
    val t1 = c.freshName("t1")
    val tdiff = c.freshName("tdiff")
    val blk = c.freshName("blk")
    val t0n = "t0"
    println(t0)
    val res = c.Expr(
      q"""
         val $kk = System.nanoTime()
         $block
         val t1 = System.nanoTime()
         val tdiff= t1 - t0
         log.debug("Took: {}", tdiff)
         $block
       """)
    println("Timing block: ")
    println(show(res))
    res
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `TermName`, you want an `Ident`:

```
val kk = Ident(TermName("kk"))
```

But if the name of the identifier is constant, there is no reason to even construct the identifier like that, when you could have just wrote:

```
q"""
   val kk = System.nanoTime
   ...
"""
```

Changing that will fix that problem, but there are others. `t0` is undefined within the quasiquotes, and all of the other term names you've defined don't actually do anything.

I don't see why you need a macro for this, either, when a normal method does the job just fine. The macro will increase the size of your code (significantly if you use it a lot).